# How to update automatically data when finished day (00:00) in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, auto-update

I am developing a project by PHP and Mysql (PhpMyadmin), so I would like to update data automatically when finished day (00:00) in mysql.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try crontab, you can execute at any date & time, if your using linux

Comment: You can even use js setTimeOut() with interval if 1 sec & call update function when its true

Comment: or use MySQL Events

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64208/scheduling-an-event-every-day-at-a-given-time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MySql-events.
Use below code for executing daily at 00:00:

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS '2014-04-30 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
  DO
    # My query
```

Use below code for executing only once at 00:00:

```
CREATE EVENT my_event
    ON SCHEDULE
  AT ('2017-03-14 00:00:00'+ INTERVAL 1 DAY) ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
    DO
  # My query
```

Also, read the [documentation on CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html).

Comment: Also mention that `event_scheduler=on` needs to be in ini file, by default it is off in many distros